# Nested ngFor using outer index in inner loop

Tags: html, css, angular, nested, ngfor

Given a list of elements:
`const l = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"]`

We want to create 1 row for every 3 elements in the list, and (up to) 3 columns per row.
In this case, the resulting html would look like:

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><p>one</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>two</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>three</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><p>four</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>five</p></div>
        <div class="col"><p>six</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><p>seven</p></div>
    </div>
```

How can I dynamically do this? The only way I can see to accomplish this is a nested ngFor loop, but there doesn't seem to be a way to use the outer index value in the inner for loop. How can one do this?

Something like:

```html
    <div *ngFor="let content of l; index as i">
        <div class="row" *ngIf="i % 3 === 0">
            <div class="col" *ngFor="<!--HOW TO ACCOMPLISH THIS FOR LOOP? j = i; j < i + 3; j++ -->">
                 <p [innerHTML]="l[j]"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why don't you create a nested array according to your requirement and use nested ngFor in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let content of [].constructor(l.length); let item_index = index">
  <div class="row" *ngIf="item_index % 3 === 0">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of [0, 1, 2]; let column_index = index">
      <ng-container *ngIf="item+item_index < l.length">
        <div class="col">
          <p [innerHTML]="l[item + item_index]"></p>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c6hxs9?file=src/app/app.component.html)